# Dart server side: How to receive data from the Postman (form-data)?

Tags: dart, dart-server

I am using `dart:io` to create the server. I send the request from the `Postman` with `form-data`. I need to use `form-data` because my old API from another language uses it and the app uses it too.

At the moment. I am trying to get the data and files with this code:

```
Future main(List<String> arguments) async {
  HttpServer server = await HttpServer.bind('localhost', 8085);
  server.listen((HttpRequest request) async {
    String jsonString = await request.cast<List<int>>().transform(utf8.decoder).join();
    print("jsonString:\n$jsonString");
    await request.response.close();
  });
}
```

When I send the data and a file from the `Postman` with this below.

[image]

I will get the error below.

```
Unhandled exception:
FormatException: Unexpected extension byte (at offset 435)
```

If I don't send the file as `image 1`, I got this.

```
jsonString:
----------------------------166099235909119466948633
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="key 1"
Content-Type: application/json

value 1
----------------------------166099235909119466948633
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="key 2"

value 2
----------------------------166099235909119466948633--
```

I can't convert the above results to variables.
I don't know how to do that. Has anyone an example for doing this or suggest any package to me? This is my first time creating a dart server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I follow [this](https://dart.dev/tutorials/server/httpserver).
You can get the data and files from the request by using [shelf_multipart](https://pub.dev/packages/shelf_multipart) (Other packages may be used in conjunction with this one and find more methods on GitHub).

If you want to see results quickly that it can be done. Follow this below.

I am using 3 packages including the [shelf](https://pub.dev/packages/shelf), [shelf_router](https://pub.dev/packages/shelf_router), and [shelf_multipart](https://pub.dev/packages/shelf_multipart) packages.

You need to add these packages to your `pubspec.yaml`.
(You can copy and paste these into your `pubspec.yaml`.)

```
dependencies:
  shelf: ^1.4.0
  shelf_router: ^1.1.3
  shelf_multipart: ^1.0.0
```

Then copy my code and past it to your `main.dart`:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:shelf/shelf.dart';
import 'package:shelf/shelf_io.dart' as shelf_io;
import 'package:shelf_router/shelf_router.dart';
import 'package:shelf_multipart/form_data.dart';
import 'package:shelf_multipart/multipart.dart';

Future main(List<String> arguments) async {
  final service = Service();
  final server = await shelf_io.serve(service.handler, 'localhost', 8085);
  print('Server running on localhost:${server.port}');
}

class Service {
  Handler get handler {
    final router = Router();

    router.post("/example", (Request request) async {
      if (request.isMultipart && request.isMultipartForm) {
        Map<String, dynamic>? data = await RequestConverter.formData(request);
        return data != null
            ? Response.ok("form-data: true, receive-data: true, data: $data")
            : Response.ok("form-data: true, receive-data: false");
      }

      return Response.ok("form-data: false");
    });

    router.all('/<ignored|.*>', (Request request) {
      return Response.notFound('Page not found');
    });
    return router;
  }
}

class RequestConverter {
  static Future<Map<String, dynamic>?> formData(Request request) async {
    try {
      Map<String, dynamic> data = {};
      Map<String, dynamic> files = {};
      final List<FormData> formDataList = await request.multipartFormData.toList();
      for (FormData formData in formDataList) {
        if (formData.filename == null) {
          String dataString = await formData.part.readString();
          data[formData.name] = Json.tryDecode(dataString) ?? dataString; //Postman doesn't send data as json
        } else if (formData.filename is String) {
          files[formData.name] = await formData.part.readBytes();
        }
      }
      return {"data": data, "files": files};
    } catch (e) {
      return null;
    }
  }
}

class Json {
  static String? tryEncode(data) {
    try {
      return jsonEncode(data);
    } catch (e) {
      return null;
    }
  }

  static dynamic tryDecode(data) {
    try {
      return jsonDecode(data);
    } catch (e) {
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

After this, you can start your server in your terminal. For me I am using:

```
dart run .\bin\main.dart
```

Finally, open the Postman and paste `http://localhost:8085/example` to the URL field, select the `POST` method, and `form-data`. You can add the data into the `KEY` and `VALUE` fields. Then press send.

This is my example in the Postman:
[image]

This solution work with `http.MultipartRequest()` from the Flutter app.